# Dynamic Views Alternative in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, dynamic, view

I am trying to create a view in mySQL that gets created or updated when a user enters a specific value (woeid). I've tried to do this with the stored procedure below:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_getChildren`(
    IN woeid INTEGER(15)
)
BEGIN
    CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `test`.`children` 
    AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM geoplanet_places gp
    WHERE gp.parent_id = woeid;
END
```

The above, or so I have read, is not possible in the current version of mySQL because a view, within a stored routine, cannot refer to routine parameters or local variables. My question would be what the reason for this is, and if there are any effective alternatives. I don't really want to create a new table and have the procedure update said table.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getChildren(IN woeid INTEGER(15))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `test`.`children` AS SELECT * FROM geoplanet_places gp WHERE gp.parent_id = ', woeid);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```