# Is there a way for CActiveRecord in Yii to only work with a subset of fields in one table?

Tags: php, yii

I am working with tables that have hundreds of fields, and I need a way for yii to work with only a subset of the fields (reading and writing). Is there some way to do so in the CActiveRecord class?

Answer (score 4):

Having hundreds of field in a table is not better.

Anyway reading & writing subset of field is possible with Yii.
I can show it with `CDbCriteria`.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'field1, field2'; // specify fields you want to read
```

While the writing you have to be clever that which field you will write when.
That can be done with `rules` in `model`.

Define `scenario` of a rule & proper validation that you want to perform on specific action.

Set scenarion before calling `$model->save()` method.

```
// Set scenarion
$model->setScenario('mystep1');
```

Apply `scenario` to model rules.

```
// You rule in model
array('email','email','on'=>'mystep1')
```

Also apply `safe` rule to only those fields on which you want to perform update operation.

```
array('email, id, name','safe')
```

safe rule is also applicable with scenario;

**Note:**
Using scenario you can save or update specific fields of table but you must need to specify the column of table by default NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my problem is that updating a lot of fields slow things down considerably, i assume this solution will speed things up?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [defaultScope()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#defaultScope-detail) function of `CActiveRecord`. It allows you to specify a condition that is added to all `SELECT` queries.

You would override the function like this:

```
public function defaultScope() {
    // by default only select records with type = 1
    return array(
        'condition' => 'type = 1',
    );
}
```

Readup:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes

Comment: No, in this case i wish to limit the columns, not the rows

Comment: It's "a bit" old topic but actually this is what you looked for. Just change "condition" to "select" and write down columns you need.

public function defaultScope() {
 return array(
  'select' => 'column1, column2',
 );
}

Answer (score 1):

According to this SO question: [Calling a database view in Yii using Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782879/calling-a-database-view-in-yii-using-active-record) you can use database **View** to make your model basing only on the columns you need.

Then you will have to find a way to **Write** (insert & update) through this view & i believe there are multiple ways to assure that.

Comment: Yes,view is another solution,but in this case my view name is dynamic, it gets tricky...

Comment: i am not sure i understood you, but `database view` can be set using `prepared statements ` to assure consistency http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424690/dynamic-views-alternative-in-mysql